# How to find the points at which a piecewise defined function is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Define $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 11 & 0 \leq  x \leq 1\\ x & 1< x \leq 2 \end{cases}$$ At what points is the function $f:[0,2]\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous?

I am pretty sure that the function is continuous at every point except for $1$, and that I should find a sequence that converges to $1$, and somehow use that to prove that the function is not continuous at $1$. Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** You're on the right track.

Remember that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if for every sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n\to x$, $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. So in order to prove that a function is discontinuous at $x$, you need to find a sequence $x_n\to x$ such that $f(x_n)\nrightarrow f(x)$.

Don't forget to prove the function is continuous elsewhere.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the answer, or is there anything wrong with the user?

Answer (score 0):

Left limit =11

lim  1+h =1
h-0+

Right limit = 1

left limit not equal to right limit. The given function is not continuous